# Executing pthread "pre init" function on thread start

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I am using an external linux library that starts pthreads.

Is there any way I can setup a trigger that calls a supplied function when a new pthread starts from the context of the thread before the threads "main" function starts?  (Like installing a signal handler or whatever)

Comment: Threads do not have their own signal handlers, so I suspect what you want to do is based on a misunderstanding. Please clarify what you really need. There's probably a much better way to do it.

Comment: @R..: Whether a new linux process (which includes threads on linux) shares its signal handler table with its parent is an option to the clone syscall.  However either way, this would not preclude a signal being sent when a new pthread starts (to the shared signal handler) if such a signal existed.  What I want to do is have a function executed when a thread starts to do some per-thread initialization - but as it is an external library I cannot modify the thread_main.  (In much the same way as pthread_key_create allows you to execute a function on thread exit)

Comment: Please explain **what** specifically you need to do in these new threads. There's probably an alternative way to achieve what you need but it's impossible to help you when you ask for a way to achieve a *mechanism* that's not possible instead of asking for a way to achieve an *effect*.

Comment: @R..: Ok, I need to call the constructors of non-POD variables that have thread_local storage duration as gcc hasn't implemented non-POD thread local variables yet.  The current workaround is to call the constructor on first use and then use pthread_key_create destructor feature to destroy them (like what boost::thread_local_ptr does), however this lazy initialization causes lag on first use is undesirable, I would rather have them initialized ahead of time.  Happy?

Comment: Are these thread_local objects used in code you provide to the library code as a callback? I was going to suggest the sort of lazy initialization you're doing now; I don't think there's any better way. Keep in mind that non-POD thread_local vars have a lot of fundamental programs (all thread_local vars do, but runtime cost is generally considered more important than memory waste) in that their constructors would run in ANY thread, even threads completely unrelated to the code that will use the objects.

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard API that does what you have asked for. There are always complex and fragile alternatives; For example, you can build a filter Shared Lib (see the option --filter=name in the man page for ld) to intercept pthread_create, and make your own wrapper function around the callers actual function for the thread.

Comment: What are the other (complex and fragile) alternatives?

Comment: Intercepting system calls, writing a kernel driver, writing a program to do binary editing on the external linux library.

Comment: GDB prints something out when a new thread starts, I wonder what mechanism it uses.

Comment: ptrace. You don't want to turn that on in production.